# Testing Visual Studio project includes all JavaScript files included in default.apsx

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, visual-studio, unit-testing

We have a C# web project that leverages AngularJS for its frontend. Our default.aspx contains all the JavaScript includes for AngularJS and supporting services - e.g. in `default.aspx`:

```
<script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="services/eventMan.js"></script>
```

In the project file (`.csproj`):

```
<Content Include="lib\angular\angular.min.js" />
<Content Include="services\eventMan.js" />
```

We use NuGet to package up the website with all the JavaScript files, etc.

On occasions it happens that we add a new service to the website, update the default.aspx but forget to update the Visual Studio project file to include the new JavaScript file. Hence when NuGet packages the website the new JavaScript file is missing and breaks during deployment.

We would like to catch such issue earlier before a deploy cycle.

Are there any ways of testing if the Visual Studio project file contains all the JavaScript files expected?

e.g. Run "something" during CI build process that would check that the `.csproj` maps to the `default.aspx` so we can know the packaging will work without deploy checking.

Comment: Does https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3678 help?

Comment: Not really unfortunately. NuGet is doing everything correctly to package things when the csproj is correct. Developers do not always remember to update the csproj file which is what causes the issue.

Comment: So you tried using `<files>` with a wildcard?

Comment: We use `<files><file src="**\*.*" exclude="..." /></files>` in our nuspec